# \titlespacing* defaults using the compact option

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

Using the `titlesec` package with the `compact` option, what are the `\titlespacing*` defaults (for `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.) for the `article` document class?  (I have the standard defaults from the package documentation but cannot find the `compact` version...)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `titlesec.sty`, one sees:

```
\DeclareOption{compact}{%
  \gdef\ttl@space{1}%
  \gdef\ttl@chapafter{30\p@}}
```

the line `\gdef\ttl@chapafter{30\p@}` simple instructs the usage of `30pt` after a chapter title and `\gdef\ttl@space{1}` indicates `1\beforetitleunit` and `1\aftertitleunit` for the spacing before and after the tiles, respectively, for lower sectional units, so the `compact` option corresponds to 
the values

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{*1}{*1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
  {0pt}{*1}{*1}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
  {0pt}{*1}{*1}
```

The default values for `\beforetitleunit` and `\aftertitleunit` are:

```
\beforetitleunit=1ex\@plus.3ex\@minus.06ex
\aftertitleunit=1ex\@plus.1ex
```

Comment: @pff You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it; in case of doubt, please see [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: One last thing, I'm not familiar with the {*1} syntax but I take it that it means 'default multiplied by 1'.  Regarding best practice, if I wanted to stretch or contract the default spacing, could I say, e.g. 


\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
  {0pt}{*0.8}{*0.8}

or should I explicitly set the spacing, e.g.

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
  {0pt}{0.8ex plus 0.24ex minus 0.048ex}{0.8ex plus 0.08ex}

Comment: @pff you're right: `*n` means multiplication by `n`, but with certain restrictions: in the `before-sep` argument this is equivalent to `n ex` with some stretchability and a minute shrinkability. In the `after-sep`, it will give some stretchability (smaller) and no shrinkability. So `*8`, for example, in the after-sep argument is not exactly `2ex plus .8ex`; the stretchability will be a little less.